# How to get bootstrap responsive (elastic) navbar link?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to get a couple of elastic (responsive?) links in a Bootstrap navbar (fixed navbar), and can't seem to get it to work. I don't need the whole navbar to be responsive and collapse automatically as I am implementing my own custom collapse behaviour below a certain screen width, but I just need a couple of the link areas on the bar to expand or shrink according to the window width, while the other buttons on the navbar remain the same size. (I have forced the link area widths with  s in the code below to make them temporarily look the right width on my screen)

Attempting to use various standard Bootstrap classes (e.g. justified buttons or justified navbar) to achieve this has either produced links that are the full width of the navbar, thus pushing all other content onto other lines, or where the link areas remain the width of their actual text content, rather than expanding to fill the available space.

I need the navbar brand logo on the far left, and on the far right I have several buttons (including drop down menus) that need to remain on the right. The space inbetween I want filled with 2 elastic/responsive link areas that change in size according to the window width.

Code is below. Feels like I am overcomplicating things but not sure how/where as need to keep my buttons on the right that are vertically centred...

Many thanks for any help or suggestions!

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-top:5px;">
         <a class="navbar-brand" style="height:30px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
      </div>

   <div style="height: 1px;"> <!-- inner div -->
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right form-inline">
         <a href="#"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; My Link Text &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </a>
         <a href="#"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; My Other Link Text &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </a>

         <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Button 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

         <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Drop down 1
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Button with another style</a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="dropdown">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="#" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false">2nd dropdown</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="saveonline">Menu item 2</a></li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- /inner div -->
  </div> <!-- /container-fluid -->
</div> <!-- /Top div -->
```

Comment: You may want to post a mockup of what you're trying to do (esp with regards to how the expandable links operate) because it isn't clear with the HTML.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. I re-thought my question and simplified it and thought it best to submit a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951382/bootstrap-navbar-with-variable-and-fixed-width-buttons